# How do I create a Generic Table(Tree/TreeGrid) with parent and child records as a Lightning Component?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript

I am trying to create a table as a lightning component that is generic ie. it can be use for any standard or custom object. I am using lightning:treeGrid for this. I have written some code for it but I'm getting some weird errors. Also, it might help if anyone knows a way to make it generic. The table looks something like this:
[image]

Errors:

[image]

[image]

Component Code:

```
<aura:component controller="AccountJson" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute type="Account[]" name="acctList"/>
    <aura:attribute name="gridColumns" type="List" />
    <aura:attribute name="gridData" type="Object" />
    <aura:attribute name="gridExpandedRows" type="Object" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <div class="slds-m-around_xx-large">
        <lightning:treeGrid aura:id="accTree" columns="{!v.gridColumns}" data="{!v.gridData}" keyField="Id"/>
    </div></aura:component>
```

JS Controller:

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var columns = [
            {
                type: 'text',
                fieldName: 'Name',
                label: 'Account Name'
            },
            {
                type: 'number',
                fieldName: 'NumberOfEmployees',
                label: 'Employees'
            },
            {
                type: 'phone',
                fieldName: 'Phone',
                label: 'Phone Number'
            },
            {
                type: 'text',
                fieldName: 'FirstName',
                label: 'First Name'
            },
            {
                type: 'text',
                fieldName: 'LastName',
                label: 'Last Name'
            },
            {
                type: 'email',
                fieldName: 'Email',
                label: 'Email'
            },
           /* {
                type: 'text',
                fieldName: 'ParentId',
                label: 'Parent Account'
            }*/
        ];

        component.set('v.gridColumns', columns);
        var action = component.get("c.getAccountList");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS" ) {
            var mp = new Map();
                var resultData = response.getReturnValue();
                for (var i=0; i<resultData.length; i++ ) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(resultData[i]));
            if(resultData[i].ParentId != null){
                alert('resultData[i].ParentId is: ' + resultData[i].ParentId);
                if(mp.get(resultData[i].ParentId) != null){
                    var c = mp.get(resultData[i].ParentId);
                    c.push(resultData[i]);
                   mp.set(resultData[i].ParentId,c);
                }
                else{
                    var arr = new Array();
                    arr.push(resultData[i]);
                    mp.set(resultData[i].ParentId,arr);
                }
            }
                  //  resultData[i]._children = resultData[i]['Contacts'];
                }
                for (var i=0; i<resultData.length; i++ ) {
    if(mp.get(resultData[i].Id) != null){
    alert('mp is: ' + JSON.stringify(mp.get(resultData[i].Id)));

    resultData[i]._children = mp.get(resultData[i].Id);
}
                }
                component.set('v.gridData', resultData);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Apex Class:

```
public with sharing class AccountJson {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Account> getAccountList() {
        List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
        accList = [SELECT Id, Name, NumberOfEmployees, Phone,ParentId FROM Account Order By Name LIMIT 20];
        return accList;
    }
}
```

Comment: seems like this error is coming from other component not from above component.

Comment: It is working as expected. No error found my side.

Comment: This error occurs when you click on the child account. Once you click on a child account, this error shows up every time you click on any record